# How to reduce execution time of Hive script

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have the following Hive script which I am running on a 16 node cluster. It takes four hours to execute; is there any chance to reduce this time?  Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO ${DestDBName}.${COUNTRY}SA_PRODUCT
SELECT '${COUNTRY}', PRDYR.YEAR, PRD.PERIOD_TYPE, RTS.PRODUCT_ID, RTS.SALES_UNITS
FROM ${DBNAME}.RETAIL_TREND_SALES RTS
JOIN ${DBNAME}.PERIOD PRD
ON RTS.PERIOD_ID = PRD.PERIOD_ID
JOIN ${DBNAME}.PERIOD_DETAIL PRDYR
ON RTS.PERIOD_ID = PRDYR.PERIOD_ID;

INSERT INTO ${DestDBName}.${COUNTRY}SA_STORE
SELECT '${COUNTRY}', PRDYR.YEAR, PRD.PERIOD_TYPE, MS.STORE_ID
FROM ${DBNAME}.MARKET_STORE MS
JOIN ${DBNAME}.PERIOD PRD
ON MS.PERIOD_ID = PRD.PERIOD_ID
JOIN ${DBNAME}.PERIOD_DETAIL PRDYR
ON MS.PERIOD_ID = PRDYR.PERIOD_ID; >> ${DataLog}
```

**Note**:  This is querying terabytes of the data on the back end.

Comment: How big are your tables MARKET_STORE, .PERIOD PRD and PERIOD_DETAIL

Comment: and what distribution are you using?

Comment: Which partition have you created in each table?